# DateTime de SQL a DateTime de JS

Tags: javascript, sql, datetime

Hola amigos tengo un endpoint que me devuevle una serie de datos de un query de SQL, entre las columas que trae mi query, viene una fecha que en sql se ve así :

> 2019-09-04 11:38:20.920

Y cuando lo renderizo a través de un **ajax** en mi tabla obtengo las fechas así:

> /Date(1567618700920)/

cuando renderizo, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/DashboardAdmin/BitacoraListJson",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (response) {


        console.log("videos: ------------ " + response);
        //alert(response);


        var resplength = response.length;
        var date = new Date();

        for (let i = 0; i <= resplength; i++) {
            document.getElementById('bitacora-t').innerHTML += `
            <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-4">`+ response[i].action + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4">`+ response[i].id_userCreated + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4">`+ response[i].created_at + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4">`+ response[i].comments + `</td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-default">ver</a></td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-danger">borrar</a></td>
        </tr>
        `;
        }


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        //$('#myModalLabel').append(`error: - ${err}`);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(err);

        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Alguien sabe como renderizar una fecha legible en **JS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola puedes probar con esto, es un modo que conozco no se si habrá un modo mas facil.

Igual y lo puedes volver una función.

Saludos

```js
var DateString='/Date(1567618700920)/'
var regex = /-?\d+/; //Agregamos una expresión regular para eliminar el /Date
        var matches = regex.exec(DateString);// Con esto regresamos lo que haga match segun la expresión
//Al hacer lo anterior obtenemos 1567618700920 
        var dt = new Date(parseInt(matches[0])); //Entonces primero lo volvemos un INT y ese INT lo convertimos a una fecha
        //Por lo tanto DT ya es una fecha

        //Creamos una variable month y obtenemos el mes +1 
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        //En esta parte validamos si el mes es 1 entonces quedaria 01 por eso el '0' pero si es mayor a 9 es decir 10,11 no es necesario
        var monthString = month > 9 ? month : '0' + month;
        //Obtenemos el dia
        var day = dt.getDate();
        //Aplicamos lo mismo que con el mes
        var dayString = day > 9 ? day : '0' + day;
        //Obtenemos el año
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        //Al final juntamos todo
        shortDate = monthString + '-' + dayString + '-' + year;
        console.log(shortDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: mil gracias funcionó increible, respuesta de los dioses

Comment: De nada Saludos