# ¿Como obtener el formato correcto en la hora?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Actualmente estoy llenando un formulario con un evento ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, v) {   
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#IdSolicitudEditar').val(v.IdExpediente);
                    $('#IDSolicitanteInformacion').val(v.IdSolicitanteInformacion);
                    $('#NumeroSolicitud').val(v.NumeroSolicitud);
                    $('#Producto').val(v.IdProducto);
                    $('#SistemaAmortizacion').val(v.SistemaAmortizacion);
                    $('#DestinoInmueble').val(v.DestinoInmueble);
                    $('#FechaEntregaInmueble').val(v.FechaEntregaInmueble);
                    $('#Constructora').val(v.Constructora);
                    $('#Proyecto').val(v.Proyecto);
                    $('#TipoDocumento').val(v.IdDocumentoIdentificativo);
                    $('#NumeroDocumento').val(v.NumeroIdentificacion);
                    $('#Nombre').val(v.Nombre);
                    $('#PrimerApellido').val(v.PrimerApellido);
                    $('#SegundoApellido').val(v.SegundoApellido);
                    $('#codOficiSegundoApellidona').val(v.SegundoApellido);
                    $('#NumeroCelular').val(v.TelefonoCelular);
                    $('#NumeroTelefono').val(v.NumeroTelefonoResidencia);
                    $('#Email').val(v.Email);
                    $('#TipoRelacionCredito').val(v.IdTipoRelacionCredito);
                    $('#FechaNacimientos').val(v.FechaNacimiento);
                    $('#FechaFirmaEscritura').val(v.FechaFirmaEscritura);
                    $('#EstadoCivil').val(v.IdEstadoCivil);
                    $('#Direccion').val(v.DireccionResidencia);
                    $('#Ciudad').val(v.IdCiudadResidencia);
                    $('#EmpleadoBanco').val(v.EmpleadoBanco);
                    $('#VIP').val(v.VIP);
                    $('#PEP').val(v.PEP);
                });
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                console.log(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

La cual se carga perfectamente en mi formulario, pero la fecha sale con un formato el cual no se como corregir

Se muestra en el input así:

> /Date(587106000000)/

imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?
Estoy trabajando con Asp.net MVC5.

Comment: Revisa este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290587/datetime-de-sql-a-datetime-de-js/290591#290591

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que formato el dato en JSON por ejemplo como siguiente:

```
date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Hay otro ejemplo:

```
var jsonDate = "\/Date(1334514600000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
console.log(date);
```

Espero que esto ayude...